# database search feature

Tags: database, query, search

I am looking to create a website that creates and searches the created database then displays the results on a custom page. I initially thought this would be a lot easier than it is proving to be. I am looking to be pointed in a direction for me to research.

Here is an example of how I would like it to work.

I would like to have one database that is generated (through a separate feature on the website or that is transferred by excel or similar) that hosts the content of a select item. In my case it would be aspects of a book. (title, author, illustrator, age range, etc...) I would like the site to have a text search box and then different filters the users can choose.

When they made the selection, the database would be searched and return a list of matches.

I would most likely being using wordpress and dreamweaver to create the website.

Thank you for any guidance you can give me!

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Development, please be specific of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use WordPress you can download a custom post type plugin  (such as [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)), create your `Book` post type; another plugin to generate your form for adding books ([Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) + [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-custom-post-types/) looks good, or a similar solution, or create a form by hand). Then tweak the default WordPress search feature to search through `Book` post type only (you can use a search engine to find out how to 'limit search to custom post type in WordPress' or something similar).

If you end up using WordPress then don't use Dreamweaver - last I checked it was for pure HTML/CSS work.